# Differences between DB2 and Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, db2

We had a talk with colleagues about databases yesterday as we will have a DB2 education in few weeks. I'm wondering, what are the differences between DB2 and Oracle as two major enterprise solutions? Are there any limitations in comparison to each other? Are there any tasks more suitable for DB2 or Oracle?

(I found [this](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Compare/oracle_vs_db2.htm) article, but I somehow doubt it covers everything)

Comment: I like this question! It'd be nice if we could use it to build up a set of clear *technical* differences between them. (I heard that there were differences in locking granularity, but that was quite a long time ago and I may have garbled it.)

Comment: You might be better off asking this question somewhere else (e.g. OracleOverflow or ServerFault), since it isn't programming-related.

Comment: The article by Alexander Chigrik referenced in this question is very outdated, even when this question was originally posted over 18 months ago. DBMS vendors seem to be releasing major changes to their database software every 12-18 months, so comparing differences between older releases is not going to give you very accurate or useful findings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The major difference in my eyes is that DB2 can tell the difference between a NULL and an empty string :-)

Comment: No, it can't: http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/t/1225.aspx

Comment: It is a matter of point of view . Having an empty piece of data is no different that having a null piece of data. Do not confuse it with  Char(0), the ASCII of Null.

Comment: With respect, it is _not_ a point of view, it is a violation of the standard. An empty piece of (known) data is not the same as an unknown NULL quantity. Classic example, people who may or may not have a middle name: "" is an attribute stating that there is no middle name, NULL is an attribute stating we don't know.

Comment: Surprisingly, many users have solved the Middle Initial problem from a practical point of view. I have no MI, but in many systems it shows up as 'X' :)

Comment: And yet my real name if Fortescue Xavier Doppleganger. That system won't work for me :-)

Comment: I know. That is the difference between real world and theoretic problems (even though these problems Do occur in the real world).

Comment: -1 The difference between NULL and empty string is minuscule: Nullish to be exact.

Comment: @Tegeri, you can vote how you see fit, that's your right. However, it doesn't make your statement any less _wrong._ There is a _vast_ difference in tri-value logic between an unknown value and a known, empty one.

Comment: A significant difference is that DB2 will allow dirty reads, I.e, 'with UR' (uncommitted read), while Oracle does not permit this.

Comment: The difference between NULL and "" is vitlaly important.
False = The answer False
"" = The is Nothing.
NULL = I dont know the answer.

You use NULL when there isnt data to put in there. You put "" When there is data and the data is blank, and of course you put False when the answer is incorrect. Also consider the commutation rules. Null as a term in an equasion will generally lead to a null result because it is unknowable. Putting a blank in however leads to a known result, as might a False.

Answer (score 5):

IMMSMW, an extremely important difference between the two is the way they achieve transaction isolation.  Oracle uses MVCC, DB2 uses traditional two-phase locking.

But that might have changed in recent DB2 releases, of course.

Comment: IMMSMW? If my memory serves me _wrong_? I think DB2 9.7 implemented MVVC, at least on the LUW side, not sure about the "real" DB2 on System z :-)

Comment: You probably won't find any mention of MVCC in the DB2 documentation, but as of version 9.7, DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows offers Currently Committed isolation, which behaves in a very similar manner to Oracle. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0053760.html

Answer (score 4):

With the release of db2 9.7  last year there are fewer differences that there every were  DB2 has licensed Postgress plus and this is in DB2 9.7. This is being used essentially a set of Oracle compatibility features. One of those features is Concurrency control. The other main ones are SQL dialect, PL/SQL, PL/SQL packages Built-in packages, JDBC client with extensions, OCI client applications, SQL*Plus scripts.    More details here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0907oracleappsondb2/

I should disclose that I work for IBM now a migration specialist.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle table, schema and column names are still limited to 30 characters, which can get annoying.

Comment: DB2 (on AIX) is limited to 8 characters. And the Username is limited to 8 characters as well, even though the OS (AIX in our case) does not have this limit.

Answer (score 2):

From which point of view?

For developers that stick to some standard, the differences should not be notable.
For admins, yes, that's another story.